# Unlabeled break must be in loop in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
sheet = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
myArray = []
batchSize = 0
sheetSize = sheet.length

eat = (item) ->
  loop
    batchSize++
    sheetSize--
    myArray.push item
        break unless batchSize < 2 or sheetSize > 0
  batchSize = 0
  document.write "myArray", myArray  
  myArray = []

eat item for item in sheet
```

http://codepen.io/nottinhill/pen/dobXvE

I want above code to print out:

```
1,2 
3,4 
5,6 
7,8 
9,10
```

However it does not work, failing with `unlabeled break must be in loop`

Comment: I get an `unexpected indentation` warning. Also that algorithm is likely not going to work that way. Do you want to "eat up" the contents of the array? then `...` might come in handy if you don't care about the sizes you have in variables. If you want it more variable, take a look at `Array.slice`

Comment: Here are [two recursive solutions for your problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNOzwb)

Comment: Completely forgot about recursiveness. That's what working at a Traditional Media Company will make of you.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. Your second algo is very elegant utilising many CoffeeScript Syntax I don't know. Wrap this as an answer below with explanatory and I will give you the answer, or if you could just explain how "start if start" works.

Answer (score 1):

per request, I'll post other solutions to the problem. I get another error message (wrong indentation) for the script in the original question so I can't answer that.

Recursive:

```
  eatVar = (batch_Size) ->
  eatSome = (sheet, start = 0) ->
    sheet.slice start,batch_Size
    end = start+batch_Size
    document.write sheet.slice start, end
    document.write "<br>"
    eatSome sheet, end if end < sheet.length
```

As to the last line: it is equivalent to

```
if end < sheet.length
  eatSome sheet, end
```

But you aren't bound to recursion:

```
eatVar2 = (batch) -> (sheet, start) ->
  position = 0
  for elem in sheet
    document.write elem
    document.write if ++position % batch then ', ' else '<br>'

(eatVar2 2) sheet
```

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNOzwb). I really hope this is some kind of assignment, because I highly discourage you to use `document.write`. There are better ways to generate HTML like `document.body.appendChild document.createTextNode "foobarbaz"`

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I'm using `document.write` just for CodePen, last time I used `document.write` in production was 1992. The function is an abstracted form of my Mongoose Workaround for the Node MongoDB Native Driver 100-Batch Limit Problem, which I might publish on my blog.

Comment: Hey, I updated the pen, there is a version with a variable function that you can replace document write with, now. Hope it helps.